# sending username to database in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf

I have created a login application in JSF 2.0 and it's working correctly . I am using MySql Database in which I have many tables. Every table contains field 'created_by'.

Now my question is how to send username(person who logs in) to 'created_by' field ?

Here is my code. Kindly tell me where I am doing wrong .

```
@ManagedBean(name = "companyController")
@SessionScoped
public class CompanyController implements Serializable {


    private Company current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB
    private session.CompanyFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean}")
    private LoginBean loginBean;

    public CompanyController() {
    }

    public Company getSelected() {
        current.setCreatedBy(loginBean.getUname());
        if (current == null) {
            current = new Company();
            selectedItemIndex = -1;
        }
        return current;
    }
```

Do I have to use setter method? If yes, why is that so? I dont understand its purpose?

Comment: So broad and vague question. What have you already tried?

Comment: Err... `modelObject.setCreatedBy(userBean.getUser())`?

Comment: Save your 'log in' user in a session variable like `sessionBean` and use it as you need it.

Comment: @skuntsel I also did the same thing but I am getting error when I am passing 'getUser()' method in it. It is returning null value. When I hardcoded it , it's working correctly. Any idea about the error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used setter method and problem got solved ! :)